# Pentaho CDE table component change drop down pagination values

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I created new CDE reports and that CDE report I was selected table component and set my datasource. In my datasource contains more records so in table component I was set paginate properties to true when I preview my dashboards then in table component shows pagination with select options with values 10,25,50,100 by default. How should I change this select options values as per user defined because instead of 10,25,50,100 in select I want to set my own values like 50,100,150,200 etc. how this should change in pentaho CDE table components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for Menu in file `script.js` (full path is `/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/pentaho-cdf/js/script.js`) and edit select option values.

OR

Go to line no 3114 in script.js (full path is same as mentioned above),find  text Menu and edit its values.

This will resolve your problem.